# Liferay deployment on weblogic10.3 fails?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, weblogic-10.x

I installed weblogic Server 10.3.Created a new domain.Downloaded liferay dependencies and additional war files.i copied the dependencies into lib folder and war into deploy folder and started server.But i am getting an error.

```
<Mar 7, 2014 2:35:20 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101342> <_appsdir_liferay-por
tal-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558_war: Error(s) encountered while pre-compiling
 jsp jspURI
 configuration.jsp:17:18: Error in "init.jsp" at line 249: The code of method _j
spService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes
limit
<%@ include file="/html/portlet/asset_publisher/init.jsp" %>
                 ^--------------------------------------^
```

Comment: I have seen this error, and from what I remember it is not a show stopper. Do you see any other error at startup?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running into [LPS-27841](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-27841). AFAIK a fix is available in EE, or you can search for the relevant commit(s) on [github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal) and apply them to your environment.

Note that Weblogic 10 is neither in the "certified" nor in the "supported" list of application servers for 6.2 (EE). E.g. it's untested and you might run into other issues. Weblogic 12 is "certified", 11 is "supported"

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                    I am also getting the same issue i am using following cong :                 liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2
weblogic 10.3.6
jdk1.7.    Can any one have solution this one

Comment: @NareshKallamadi 6.1 EE GA3 is available, also several servicepacks. Please try if those fixes help, but note that technically Weblogic 10 is neither on the "supported" nor on the "certified" list - which doesn't mean it won't run or you can't get fixes... You might want to contact support if the last version doesn't work. But try that one first - odds are that it's long fixed.